# Как мониторить открытие блока onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Веду разработку [здесь](http://an-alternativa.com.ua/). На [внутренней странице товара](http://an-alternativa.com.ua/viewprofile.php?id=90) по ссылкам "Связаться", "В избранное", "В черный список" и т. п. получаем на выход пустой экран вместо ожидаемого мини-блока входа. Случилось горе сие после смены шапочных файлов дизайна (хоть и экспортировалось максимально аккуратно). Посоветуйте, как правильно мониторить ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб отлавливать ошибки такого плана, я советую использовать плагин [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/) для [Firefox](http://mozilla-russia.org/products/firefox/).
В общем-то, вот ошибки, которые этот самый [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/) показал:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://an-alternativa.com.ua/templates/default_theme/css/system.css 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://an-alternativa.com.ua/templates/default_theme/css/general.css 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://an-alternativa.com.ua/templates/default_theme/js/jquery/jquery.js 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://an-alternativa.com.ua/templates/default_theme/js/jquery/jquery.js 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://an-alternativa.com.ua/templates/default_theme/css/images/arrow3.png
```

Для начала, проверьте пути к файлу **jquery.js** , да и к css-файлам тоже не мешало бы проверить.